# How do I change where Bash looks for Python in Linux?

Tags: python, linux, bash

I just updated my ReadyNas from python 2.3.5 to python 2.6.6. The upgrade placed the new version in the `/usr/local/bin` directory. So

- `/usr/local/bin/python` is Python 2.6.6
- `/usr/bin/python`       is Python 2.3.5

When I type `python` at a bash prompt tries to run `/usr/bin/python` or my old version. I relocated my old version, and now I get:

```
bash: /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

How can I change where bash looks for python? How is bash currently deciding that when I type `python` that it only looks in `/usr/bin` for python?

Comment: I guess I should have said the following. Even when I am in the directory /usr/local/bin that contains my new python (2.6.6) and type python it doesn't look locally first, it only looks for it in /usr/bin. Why is that?

Comment: I suppose you've probably found out by now, but someone else might find this useful: the current directory is not normally in `PATH`, for [security and stability reasons](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65700).

Answer (score 16):

Your `PATH` environment variable. It has a list of directories which bash searches (in the same order) when it's looking for an program to execute. Basically you want to put `/usr/local/bin` at the start of your `PATH` environment variable. Add the following to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

You can have a look at the current setting by running the `set` command in bash.

Alternatively, you can simply rename `/usr/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python2.3` and create a symlink pointing to the new version, e.g.

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: You might add the other option of symlinking from `/usr/bin`. The only reason I say this is that occasionally you don't want *everything* in `/usr/local/bin` to be the first choice.

Comment: No, linking /usr/bin/foo is **never** a good option. It's tied to what it is for a reason. Just modify your PATH variable and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's BASH responsibility to choose the default version for the Python interpreter.

If you're the administrator, the cleanest way to do this is to use a symbolic link in `/usr/bin/python` pointing to the appropiate version. Avoid replacing the actual binaries if possible.

If you're not, then add a `bin` folder somewhere you have access to, and prepend it to the `$PATH` environment variable. Then create a symlink to the desired version of the python interpreter.

Cheers!

Comment: No, this is never the best way -- /usr/bin/python is linked to what it is because the package manager wanted it to be. Messing with it is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: However, the last paragraph's advice for non-admins is useful.